# Karnaugh Map from this expression?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, karnaugh-map

Here is the expression I am trying to represent in the Karnaugh Map:

[image]

This is what I have done: Can somebody confirm if this is right? I have done the truth table right, however I am having doubts on whether the map has been done correctly.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Seems correct. \$\overline{(xy)}\$ simplifies to \$\overline{x}+\overline{y}\$. Then withinin the left part you get a \$\overline{x}+x\$ which is always 1, so only the right part is of interest. The right part is exactly the same as your K-map.

Comment: @jippie, you should post your comment as an answer so that this question does not remain unanswered.

Comment: @jippie - I understood what you mean, but do i have to change anything on the picture above or is that right?

Comment: Also asked at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1169384/18398

Comment: @Mathematica not in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Your K-Map is correct.

> R = (**X + X'** + Y' + Z)(XY + X'Y'Z+YZ')
>
> R = (**1 + Y' + Z**)(XY + X'Y'Z+YZ')
>
> R = **(1)(XY + X'Y'Z+YZ')**
>
> R = XY + X'Y'Z+YZ'
>
> R = **XYZ'** + XYZ + X'Y'Z + **XYZ'** + X'YZ'
>
> R = XYZ + X'Y'Z + XYZ' + X'YZ'

respective terms of last equation will be logic one in K-Map